# How can I display image clearly in xterm

Tags: terminal, xterm, images

All of the open source software that I used，only w3m can display image clearly,I want to try to display image in xterm,how can I accomplish it? I tried 'tput' command to change the color of output characters to display a similar photo.

Comment: [Raster graphics in xterm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2114347/995714)

Answer (score 5):

`w3m` uses a trick to show an image on top of an `xterm` window, and according to a comment in the code, that applies to more than one terminal emulator.  The trick relies upon finding a suitable X window by looking for the `WINDOWID` of the terminal.

Refer to [w3m/w3mimg/x11/x11_w3mimg.c](https://github.com/tokuhirom/w3m/blob/master/w3mimg/x11/x11_w3mimg.c) to see how it does this.

As for [`tput`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html): it is not used for drawing images on a terminal.  It retrieves *capabilities* from the terminal database and (with either exit-codes or writing text) makes the capabilities available for use in scripts that manipulate the terminal.

`xterm` usually (not always: it's been *optional* since [1997](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_57)) comes with a [Tek4014 emulator](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Tektronix-4014-Mode) which can be used for vector graphics.  `w3m` does not use that.

Comment: See also [terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) for a terminal emulator that can embed images.

Comment: I'd rather not discuss that program, since much of its discussion of terminal emulation is less than useful.  Ditto for Final Term.